# Terraform "for_each" with "if" dynamic rule

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have dynamic terraform rule that enables traffic for VM

```
module "nonfunctional" {
  source         = "../../modules/additionalvms"
  resource_group = var.resource_group
  vmname        = "nf-add-vm"
  instances = {
    TICKET-F2345 = { name = "F2345", status = "enabled-oa" }
    TICKET-F2471 = { name = "F2371" }   
  }
}
```

The firewall policy works well and the code is:

```
resource "azurerm_firewall_policy_rule_collection_group" "policy-additionalvms" {
  name               = "policy-additionalvms"
  firewall_policy_id = data.azurerm_firewall_policy.nonfunctional.id
  priority           = 2300
  application_rule_collection {
    name     = "policy-additionalvms"
    priority = 2312
    action   = "Allow"
    dynamic "rule" {
      for_each = var.instances
      content {
        name = "allow-web-out-${rule.key}"
        protocols {
          type = "Http"
          port = 80
        }
        protocols {
          type = "Https"
          port = 443
        }
        source_addresses  = [azurerm_network_interface.additionalvms[rule.key].private_ip_address]
        destination_fqdns = ["*"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But now i have added another property and need to add condition that only selected VMs will have http/s access. I need to put condition "if status = "enabled-oa"" than VMs will have access, otherwize - not. I have created this condition but it does not work:

```
resource "azurerm_firewall_policy_rule_collection_group" "policy-additionalvms" {
   name               = "policy-additionalvms"
   firewall_policy_id = data.azurerm_firewall_policy.nonfunctional.id
   priority           = 2300
  application_rule_collection {
    name     = "policy-additionalvms"
    priority = 2312
    action   = "Allow"
    dynamic "rule" {
      for_each = { for name, instance in var.instances : name => instance if var.instances.status == "enabled-oa"}
      content {
        name = "allow-web-out-${rule.key}"
        protocols {
          type = "Http"
          port = 80
        }
        protocols {
          type = "Https"
          port = 443
        }
        source_addresses  = [azurerm_network_interface.additionalvms[rule.key].private_ip_address]
        destination_fqdns = ["*"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting this error:

> │     │ var.instances is map of map of string with 2 elements
> │
> │ This map does not have an element with the key "status".

How can I do "for_each" with "if" at the same time? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the variable you are passing to the module is a map of maps, then you need something like this:

```
{ for name, instance in var.instances : name => instance if try(instance.status, "") == "enabled-oa" }
```

Note that I had to use the `try` function since the second element of the map does not have a key named `status`. If you want to avoid using the `try` built-in function, you would need to set the `status` to an empty (or any other) string which will then make `if` condition work only for `enabled-oa`. So the code should be:

```
resource "azurerm_firewall_policy_rule_collection_group" "policy-additionalvms" {
  name               = "policy-additionalvms"
  firewall_policy_id = data.azurerm_firewall_policy.nonfunctional.id
  priority           = 2300
  application_rule_collection {
    name     = "policy-additionalvms"
    priority = 2312
    action   = "Allow"
    dynamic "rule" {
      for_each = { for name, instance in var.instances : name => instance if try(instance.status, "") == "enabled-oa" }
      content {
        name = "allow-web-out-${rule.key}"
        protocols {
          type = "Http"
          port = 80
        }
        protocols {
          type = "Https"
          port = 443
        }
        source_addresses  = [azurerm_network_interface.additionalvms[rule.key].private_ip_address]
        destination_fqdns = ["*"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you  very much @marko-e. Works perfectly. Correct code is `for_each = { for name, instance in var.instances : name => instance if try(instance.status, "") == "enabled-oa" }`

Comment: Ah, yes, I used local to test, fixed. :)